# Is there a way to query for a Firestore collection to get the number of times a field's value occurs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

What I am trying to do is to query a Collection in such a way that:
1. I can get the number of times the value `true` occurs in all documents
[image]

Like, is there a way to check through each document and query for document fields matching `true` ?

2. After that, store the number of times that `true` value occurs in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different possible approaches:

#### 1. Fetch all documents with field `TransmitterError == true`

You can write a query that will return all the documents and use the `size` property of the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html):

```
db.collection("Londiani Hill").where("TransmitterError", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log(querySnapshot.size);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

The problem with this approach is that you read **all the documents** with a field `TransmitterError = true` **each time you want to count them** and this has a cost.

#### 2. Maintain a counter

You can increment a counter each time you create a document with field `TransmitterError = true` (and decrement it if you delete the doc or change the value of `TransmitterError` to `false`). You will need to maintain one counter per collection.

For implementing the counter you can either use a [Distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) per collection OR use one "counter" document per collection where you have a counter field that you increment with `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()`, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

The selection criteria between the two types of the counter is the number of times a counter for a specific collection will be updated: as a matter of fact, in Cloud Firestore, **you can only update a single document about once per second**. So if you know that counter's documents might be updated more than once per second, you should choose the distributed counters approach, otherwise, you can rely on one counter document per collection.

Comment: This approach looks good but it was what I was avoiding. To query for each field. Isn't there a way to just look through all the documents without specifying the field? Just the occurence of ```true```

Comment: No, you cannot, with the Client SDKs, query only a subset of a document fields. This is possible with the REST API but not with the Client SDKs. But this is not the main problem: you could maintain a parallel collection with documents with the same UID and only the TransmitterError field. The main problem is that you read all the documents with field TransmitterError = true each time you want to count them and this has a cost (https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: So in your opinion, this approach is going to be costly. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Might this help you to solve problem

```
db.collection("Londiani Hill").where("TransmitterError", "==", true).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {      
    console.log(querySnapshot.size); 
});
```