# Flutter Firestore count documents real-time

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code in my flutter project which counts the number of documents in a collection where "accepted" is "pending".

```
QuerySnapshot notifNum = await orders.where("id",isEqualTo:_auth.currentUser.uid).where("accepted",isEqualTo: "pending").get();
```

Then I make a list of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot and get it's length, to get the number of notifications:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> _notifc = notifNum.docs;
int notifCount = _notifc.length;
```

However, I want to make it real time so that, when a document is updated from "pending" to "accepted", the number of notifications is automatically updated. I tried using snapshots, but they didn't display any number. How can I make it work?

```
StreamBuilder<int>(
                        stream: _orders
                            .where("ustaId",isEqualTo:_auth.currentUser.uid)
                            .where("acceptedByUsta", isEqualTo: "pending")
                            .snapshots().length.asStream(),
                        builder: (context,snapshot) {
                          if(snapshot.hasError){
                            return Text("zzz");
                          }

                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text("Loading");
                          }
                          if(snapshot.hasData){
                            print("aa");
                          }else{
                            print("zzz");
                          }
                          return new Positioned(
                                right: 0,
                                child: new Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                  ),
                                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                    minWidth: 15,
                                    minHeight: 12,
                                  ),
                                  child: new Text(
                                    "aaa",
                                    style: new TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                    ),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                        }),
```

[image]

Comment: Note that with a solution that consists in reading all the documents corresponding to the query, each time you want to count them you will be charge for the read of ALL those documents. This can rapidly generates a high cost if you have a lot of docs and read the counter frequently. Have look a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819527/3371862) to see another solution based on counters.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to implement the required functionality.

1. You need to create a stream that returns the total number of `documents` where key 'accepted' has a value 'pending'.
2. Encapsulate your widget that shows the count inside of a `StreamBuilder` or use `StreamProvider` somewhere above the `Scaffold' of the *Widget displaying the count*.
3. Get data from the `StreamBuilder` and display on the widget.

> Stream autoupdates whenever their is a change in the Firestore
> document.

I have changed my code to fit your need.

1. Stream that returns count

   ```
     Stream<QuerySnapshot> requestCount() {
         return orders
         .where("ustaId",isEqualTo:_auth.currentUser.uid)
         .where("acceptedByUsta", isEqualTo: "pending")
         .snapshots();

         }
   ```
2. Use a StreamBuilder

   ```
   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: requestCount(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){

        if (snapshot.hasData){

          return Text(snapshot?.data.size.toString() ?? '0');
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
       }
      )
   ```

Comment: How do I count the DocumentSnapshot numbers In streambuilder?

Comment: @IBMR Just edited my answer and added details to help you implement what you want.

Comment: @IBMR Edited my answer, since you only wanted length of `QuerySnapshot`.
Check it out and provide your feedback :)

Comment: Thank you, however the stream: requestCount returns the following error ```The argument type 'Stream<int> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<int>'.```

Comment: Can you point to the line which throws this error?

Comment: It was ``` stream: requestCount,``` line. I copied the Stream in point one and replaced request Count with that. However, I don't get get any text.

Comment: I posted the last version in the edit. I don't get anything printed nor in the widget.

Comment: You haven't used the value `snapshot.data`.

Please recheck you keys.

Comment: I changed now, it's still the same.

Comment: I don't think the code even reaches the ```builder```, because I put a print at the very top, it didn't print it.

Comment: How is your database structure?
Can you add some details about that in your answer?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the collection and a document in my edit.

Comment: Tried the previous code and it didn't work.
Edited it and now it works, try it and provide feedback :)